# Inserting a new column always before a certain heade

Tags: excel, vba

With Excel VBA, I would like to have a button which adds a new 'Feature #' column before the 'Total' column, every time the button is pressed.

Basically, a button that does the following, from image 1 -> 2 -> 3.

**1.**
[image]

**2.**
[image]

**3.**
[image]

**Update:**
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Table is from `Cell A2` try the following:

```
Sub InsertColumn()
    Dim lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long

    lastColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Columns(lastColumn - 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Cells(2, lastColumn).Value = "Feature" & " " & lastColumn - 1
    Range(Cells(3, lastColumn), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).ClearContents
    Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:
**_________________________________________________________________________________**

This code should work for updated question or the image added.

```
Sub InsertColumn111()
    Dim lastColumn As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim rConstants As Range

    lastColumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Columns(lastColumn - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Cells(2, lastColumn).Value = "Feature" & " " & lastColumn - 1
    Range(Cells(3, lastColumn), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).ClearContents

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(lastRow - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToBottom
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "Feature" & " " & lastRow - 7
    Set rConstants = Range(Cells(lastRow, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    rConstants.ClearContents

    Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mrig, underneath my data table, I have a data that feeds my Waterfall chart.  Could you modify your answer to add a row to the table for my Waterfall chart?  (I added a photo above).

Comment: @Nick - You just want to add another row or does row have formulas also.

Comment: I would like the new rows to have the same formulas contained in the Formula 1-Formula 6 rows.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Nick - So as per the image, row for `Feature 7` should be added between `Feature 6` and `Product 2`.

Comment: @Nick - I have a question, where are you getting values/formulas from in that table.

Comment: I got the formulas from the following website, under "Floating Column Chart Data and Calculations": http://peltiertech.com/excel-waterfall-charts-bridge-charts/

Comment: I am receiving the error: No Cells were Found, and it debugged to this line: `Set rConstants = Range(Cells(lastRow, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

Comment: @Nick - What is it?

Comment: see comment above yours.

Comment: I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614257/adding-a-row-and-a-column-with-the-same-vba-button

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data starting with A1 (Pls. refer the image below)

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    columntoinsert = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    Columns(columntoinsert).Insert
    Cells(1, columntoinsert) = "Feature" & columntoinsert - 1
End Sub
```

[image]

---

After the button click:

[image]